# IronRouter Router.onBeforeAction redirect and waitOn

Tags: meteor

I have a conventional IronRouter setup using a `Router.onBeforeAction` hook to redirect users to the login page if they try to access a page which requires to be logged in.

However, if the route one tries to access - which requires a logged in user - has a `waitOn` property with subscriptions, the application just hangs.

After a while, I figured out, that I have to wrap all the subscriptions in a `if( Meteor.user() )` block to get the redirect working.

I guess I understand the reason, but it feels a bit odd to have to check for the Meteor user in the `waitOn` subscriptions. Is there a way to cancel the subscriptions in the `onBeforeAction` hook function?

Comment: Put code you did so far so we can help you more specifficaly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. When you subscribe with params it's a good practice to check the arguments. Placing this check at `onBeforeAction` will make your application harder to maintain. You'll need a list of pages/routes that need a login so you can redirect to home/login/etc. If you want to display some information on a page that requires a login, instead of redirecting, you can display some data. It's a lot easier to do this validation on each controller.